# RethinkDB filter not finding results

Tags: javascript, node.js, rethinkdb

I have an issue with RethinkDB (NodeJS).

I'm trying to use a simple .filter() function but for some unknown reason it doesn't want to find a result. Currently my code looks like this:

```
     const someID = 1234;

     r.table('list').filter({id: someID}).run().then((err, result) =>{
      if(err) throw err;
      console.log(result)
     })
```

I know that the result with ID '1234' is there because if I run this query:

```
     const someID = 1234;

     r.table('list').filter({id: 1234}).run().then((err, result) =>{
      if(err) throw err;
      console.log(result)
     })
```

It works just fine.

the only change I made is give the ID directly instead of making it a variable/constant.

What might be the issue?

Comment: Have you tried rewriting the filter method using a callback function instead of an object?

Comment: I've tried it. I've tried literally everything. Including .gt() and other functions like that.

Comment: Ultimately, are you just trying to select one item from a table based on a single property? Or is the ultimate use case more complicated than that?

Comment: Im trying to get just one result from a database. Then Im editing and updating it. Updating as in pushing into the database.

So yes, basically I just want to get it. The ID varies so I can't hard-code it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having the same issue, I've resolved it by changing my object in the database. I've deleted my `id` field so Rethink Generates it's own key, and now I'm using that as my object id. It works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching by the primary index of a table (usually `id`), then `get` is probably the tool you are looking for:

```
const itemId = 1234;

r.table('list').get(itemId)
```

If you are looking for something based on a secondary key, then `getAll` will serve your purposes:

1. Create the key, if necessary:

   ```
   r.table('list').indexCreate('val')
   ```
2. Access the data:

   ```
   const itemVal = 'hey'

   r.table('list').getAll(itemVal, {index: 'val'})

   // would return data like: { id: 1234, val: 'hey' }
   ```

It appears that the first use case is what you're looking for, but I thought you might find the second helpful.

Comment: I can't seem to get any results from that. Rethink is not returning anything. Maybe I'm just confused. 

My object looks like that:

    {
        "id": "1234",
        "data": "placeholder",
        "timestamp": 145423213
    } So I'm not sure if we mean the same thing by primary index

Comment: Maybe you are looking a number when you should be looking for a string for the ID?

Comment: I've tried it with JSON.stringify(itemId), the output was still an empty array.

Comment: It’s starting to sound like maybe your data doesn’t contain an item with an ID of 1234...

Comment: Try `r.table('list')` and double check it is there.

Comment: That was my first thought. But then I got all the items from rethink without filtering, copied the object id from the result and hard coded it into the filter, it worked without any issues. Then I changed itemID constant, changed the filter and it doesn't work.

Comment: I've just tried that. Im getting 'Unhandled rejection (<(empty array)>, no stack trace)
'

Comment: Man alive. Maybe post some more code and show your exact database structure (if you’re allowed)

Comment: What exactly would you like to see?

Comment: Let’s start with the exact output from r.table(‘list’)

Comment: [
  {
    "entries": 3,
    "id": 1357186,
    "price": 4,
    "list": [
      {
        "some": 0,
        "object": {}
      },
      {
        "placeholder": 1,
        "object": {}
      },
      {
        "data": 2,
        "object": {}
      }
    ]
  }
]

Comment: That's the output with valued changed for privacy reasons

Comment: Oh, I see. You are trying to access nested data, this is not at the top level.

Comment: Out of the output you posted, which one would you be trying to access, in this scenario?

Comment: This is the only object in the database, just for simplicity. I'm trying to access it.

Comment: Well then what is the name of that table? Because you used the example of 'list' but then you used list as a row in your object, so that’s probably your confusion at this point.

Comment: Oh, my bad. The name of the table is completely different, 'games'. List is just a nested array. My query is  r.table('games')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186272/discussion-between-ben-steward-and-nilmex).